# How to filter a collection of objects

Tags: c#, collections

I have a animal class. a herbivore class which inherits from animal and a elephant class which inherits from herbivore. I also have a carnivore class which inherits from animal and a tiger class which inherits from carnivore. I Have a observable collection called zoo with tigers and elephants. I have a listbox hooked up to the zoo collection. How do I filter for example when a button in clicked just to show tigers or eg to show elephants.I tried this eg
buttonCLick event

```
        ObservableCollection<Animal> veg = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();

        foreach (Herbivore h in lstBoxAnimals.Items)
        {
            veg.Add(h);
        }
        lstBoxAnimals.ItemsSource = veg;
```

Invalid cast exception was error message is there a different way of doing this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
foreach (var h in lstBoxAnimals.Items.OfType<Herbivore>())
{
  veg.Add(h);
}
```